# How to access variables created dynamically inside functions and methods in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, function, scope

I can't access variables created dynamically in a function or method of my objects in PHP. It is probably a matter of scope, but I do not know why this happens as in JavaScript when you declare a var inside a function you can still access it outside that function.

What I'm doing is this:

```
#code
...

$inputs = ['olympiad', 'test_type', 'year', 'level', 'country', 'test', 'answersheet'];

$Form = new Form;
$Form->addFields($inputs);

foreach (array_keys($Form->fields) as $key) {
  ${"$key"} = $Form->fields["$key"];
}

$olympiad->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($olyimpiadsArray)->label('Olmpíada')->errorMessage('some error message here');
$test_type->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($testTypeArray)->errorMessage('bla bla');
$level->required(true)->type('select')->inValues(['Nacional', 'Regional'])->label('Nível')->errorMessage('sample error message');
$year->required(true)->type('int')->range(1998, 2019)->label('Ano')->errorMessage('another error message');
$country->required(true)->type('string')->range(4, 64)->label('País')->errorMessage('these arent the real error messages');
$test->type('file')->label('Prova')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla');
$answersheet->type('file')->label('Gabarito')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla bla');
```

That works because the Fields are objects and they are passed as reference, so I can access these objects through the created variables inside the `foreach` and the Form will also be able to validate the Field objects.

I'm using the same `foreach` in many webpages, so it is quite awkward because I'm copying and pasting the code, again and again.

EXPECTED RESULTS

What do I want? I want to do this:

```
Class Form {
  #code
  ...
  public function create_vars_for_fields() {
    foreach(array_keys($this->fields) as $key) {
      ${"$key"} = $this->fields["$key"];
    }
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Then, on my PHP webpages I shoul be able to do this:

```
require_once 'Form.php';

$inputs = ['olympiad', 'test_type', 'year', 'level', 'country', 'test', 'answersheet'];

$Form = new Form;
$Form->addFields($inputs)->create_vars_for_fields();

#code
...
//here I should be able to access my variables, which are now objects of the class Fields
echo $test_type->value; //should echo the test type of the olympiad, which is equal to $_POST['test_type']
echo $country->value; //should echo the country of the olympad, which is equal to $_POST['country']
```

However, the code above throws many errors saying that these variables are undefined.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: olympiad in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\phpFormBuilder\tests\TestValidation.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function required() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\phpFormBuilder\tests\TestValidation.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\phpFormBuilder\tests\AddTest.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\phpFormBuilder\tests\TestValidation.php on line 8
```

Line 8 is the line I say `$olympiad->required(true)`

How can I access these variables by creating them dynamically in a function or method?

Comment: `var` sort of equiv to `global` but using globals in PHP or any language is a recipt for eventual disaster

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  ${"$key"} = $value;
}` Another disaster waiting to happen (Security wise) and could have been done simpler using `extract()` ___But thats NOT a suggestion either___

Comment: If you have an Object for your $_POST vars then create PROPERTIES of the same name then use `$Form->Name` for example

Comment: RiggsFolly, you said '' If you have an Object for your $_POST vars then create PROPERTIES of the same name then use $Form->Name for example ''. Although is was not explicit on the form, it is actually what I'm doing now with my Form Class.

Comment: Why did you vote my post down?

Comment: Because you take every occurance in $_POST and make a variable in the main scope out of it. Thats what previous versions of PHP did automatically and then STOPPED doing that because it was insecure. Remember I can post this script any $_POST values I like to invent, possibly overwriting one of yours with my new data :) Like maybe `is_logged_in` as an example

Comment: This line `$fields = ['author', 'publication_date', 'category', 'title'];` does not set `$Form->fields`

Comment: Maybe if you show us the code you are using. And the errors that are being generated by it, we could better help you

Comment: You are right. Indeed, that is something I used to do untill some time ago when I created my Form Class. As I said in the edited question, I'm declaring the name of my variables in an array first, then I'm taking them like the following: `$inputs = ['olympiad', 'test_type', 'year', 'level', 'country', 'test', 'answersheet'];
$Form = new Form; $Form->addFields($inputs);`. I don't see why you voted it down. Could you undo this?

Comment: Ok, I gonna share the real code here.

Comment: **You are not doing** `$Form = new Form; $Form->addFields($inputs);` **in the script you show us in your question**

Comment: @StudentofSciences - you're clearly trying to find better ways to organize/write your code. Great! Maybe it's time to look into a framework to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: `${"$key"} = $Form->fields["$key"];` will not make a property of that object. You need to do `$this->{"$key"} = $Form->fields["$key"];` BUT it would be simpler and cleaner to pass the fields array as a parameter on `public function create_vars_for_fields($fields) {`

Comment: I also suggest you rename `create_vars_for_fields()` to `create_properties_for_fields()` so you dont forget what you are trying to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry for denying the code. I was afraid someone would take my ideas;  that is way I did not provide the right code. Also, in the last few days I changed my code, so the code I had provided before was not up-to-date. Now I pasted the code I'm using now.

Comment: For future reference: You show us PSEUDO code we give you PSEUDO answers. Thats all we can do. We can only comment on what we can see.

Comment: And all the Historyonics is just obscuring the actual questoin. Can I suggest you remove that

Comment: @RiggsFolly Which Hystoryonics? If you think there is unnecessary information you can edit the post and delete that information.

Comment: All the bit about what I used to do etc etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly about the insecurity issues of  `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { ${"$key"} = $value; }`, it is indeed very insecure and I discovered that it is know as `Mass assignment vulnerability`. I'm glad I don't do that anymore under any circumstances and I have never done that in production (I did that in dev some months ago).  I'm glad you alerted me that; next time you are going to help someone else it would be even cooler if you give the specific name of the vulnerability. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a smart, clear way to accomplish this! The solution uses `extract` built-in function.

Although I do not need it anymore because I'm using Laravel for validation, I still want to share the answer so it can help others.

**SOLUTION**

```
Class Form {
  #code
  ...
  public function getFieldsCompacted() {
    $compactedFields = [];
    foreach(array_keys($this->fields) as $key) {
      $compactedFiels["$key"] = $this->fields["$key"];
    }
    return $compactedFields;
  }
}
```

Then, on the code:

```
require_once '/path/to/Form.php';

$inputs = ['olympiad', 'test_type', 'year', 'level', 'test', 'answer_sheet'];
$Form = new Form;
$Form->addFields($inputs);
extract($Form->getFieldsCompacted());
```

This way I can do:

```
$olympiad->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($olyimpiadsArray)->label('Olimpíada')->errorMessage('some error message here');
$test_type->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($testTypeArray)->errorMessage('bla bla');
$level->required(true)->type('select')->inValues(['Nacional', 'Regional'])->label('Nível')->errorMessage('sample error message');
$year->required(true)->type('int')->range(1998, 2019)->label('Ano')->errorMessage('another error message');
$test->type('file')->label('Prova')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla');
$answersheet->type('file')->label('Gabarito')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla bla');
```

Instead of doing:

```
$Form->fields['olympiad']->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($olyimpiadsArray)->label('Olimpíada')->errorMessage('some error message here');
$Form->fields['test_type']->required(true)->type('select')->inValues($testTypeArray)->errorMessage('bla bla');
$Form->fields['level']->required(true)->type('select')->inValues(['National', 'State'])->label('Nível')->errorMessage('sample error message');
$Form->fields['year']->required(true)->type('int')->range(1998, 2019)->label('Ano')->errorMessage('another error message');
$Form->fields['test']->type('file')->label('Prova')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla');
$Form->fields['answersheet']->type('file')->label('Gabarito')->allowedExtensions(['pdf'])->errorMessage('bla bla bla');
```

**Edit:**

RiggsFolly pointed out the insecurity of using `extract`. I totally agree that using `extract` in `$_POST` and `$_GET`. However, this is not the case here because the variables  to  extract are defined as you can see in 
`$inputs = ['olympiad', 'test_type', 'year', 'level', 'test', 'answer_sheet'];`. So, the `extract` will only extract these variables and it won't override other variables. Therefore, no risk in the code above.

Comment: Extract is also one of those "Dont Use" functions

Comment: Can you explain why `Extract` is one of 'Dont Use' functions?